# Entity Framework DataGridView binding source

Tags: c#, datagridview, entity-framework-6

I am discovering Entity Framework, I have a winforms project and a database running on SQLserver which has 2 Tables: `Student` and `Standard`.
First I created a ADO.NET Entity Data Model from the database with the wizard help thing. Then I have a DataGridView control which has a bindingsource as DataSource.
The DataGridView is correctly populated with the fields from `Student` table BUT what i'd like to do is add a column to the same DataGridView but with data coming from the `Standard` table. Take a look at the picture : [image]

I'm stuck here i don't know how to do this.

Comment: Without seeing your binding code, it probably looks something like dataGridView1.DataSource = ctx.Students.ToList(); so just include the related records: dataGridView1.DataSource = ctx.Students.Include(s=>s.Standard).ToList(); then you should be able to access Student.Standard.StandardName.

Comment: i'm confused on how to do it, do i have to use a binding source? if not how do i modify the columns with the visual form editor. I have       `studentBindingSource.DataSource = context.Students.Include(s => s.Standard).ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = studentBindingSource;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
public class DataBindingProjection
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public date DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Height { get; set; }
    public string Weight { get; set; }
    ... etc.
    public string StandardName { get; set; 
}
```

In your Load() or OnClick():

```
var query = context.Students
                   .Include(s => s.Standard)
                   .Select(s => new DataBindingProjection
                    {
                       StudentName = s.StudentName,
                       DateOfBirth = s.DateOfBirth,
                       Height = s.Height,
                       Weight = s.Weight,
                       ...
                       StandardName = s.Standard.StandardName
                    };

dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "StudentName";
dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "DateOfBirth";
dataGridView1.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "Height";
dataGridView1.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "Weight";
dataGridView1.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "StandardName";
```

Or you can manually add these into the designer.

Comment: I can get the columns populated but only with code, it seems when i try with the designer it's not picking up the changes i made in code behind, for example after i bind BindingSource to the gridview with code, when i flip to the designer, the datasource property of the gridview is not set?? so i can't modify the columns with the designer